# Zenity File Selection - Change Display Options?

Tags: debian, zenity

Zenity version **3.22** (**Debian Stretch**).

```
ls -a foobar
.  ..  directory  foo  .foo
```

`zenity --file-selection --filename=/tmp/foobar/`

yields (after a right click):

[image]

I know that I can just click on the **Show Hidden Files** option in order to view the hidden files, but what can I do so that said **Show Hidden Files** option is always checked whenever I run the above `zenity...` command?

As a matter of fact, what I would like to *always* come up is:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the **[GNOME System 3 Administration Guide](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/gsettings-browse.html.en)**.

Load the **dconf-editor** package, then open the **dconf Editor**.

Drill down to **org** -> **gtk** -> **settings** -> **file-chooser**. Ensure the following settings:

**show-hidden** = **true**

**show-size-column** = **false**

**sort-directories-first** = **true**

End of problem...

Comment: underrated answer, +1